# How to access Atom workspace directory in a Python script

Tags: javascript, python, electron, atom-editor

I was working on a Python script, and  wanted to access Atom's  current working directory in that script.

Atom is built on electron.js, and the way you do it in JavaScript is:

```
let filePath = atom.workspace.getActiveTextEditor().getPath();
```

I want this variable (simply the directory) in my Python script instead.

Comment: It would help if you could provide more context about what you're trying to do here. You can execute your Python script using JavaScript and pass the path as an argument, I guess. But I don't see the point in doing that.

Comment: @idleberg I want to use a python script independently. The script would create some directories inside the working directory of Atom, and I will trigger this script with a plugin I'm creating.

Comment: When you say "plugin", do you mean an Atom package?

Comment: @idleberg yes, my bad I meant package.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Unfortunately, SO isn't a code conversion site; You are expected to research, then try writing the code yourself, and if you run into a problem ask a specific question about that particular problem. Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages along with "[“Please convert my code to X” questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54345)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea of what you're trying to achieve is giving me some headaches. While it's certainly possible to invoke the Python interpreter from JavaScript, it's probably not the best user experience for people using your package.

Before even running the Python script, the package needs to check at least the following:

- user has the correct version of Python installed
- `python` is exposed to the `PATH`
- the active file is eligible to be interpreted by Python

These are different problems, but nevertheless some you need to sort out.

You haven't specified, whether you invoke the Python script within a synchronous or asynchronous function. I'm going to assume the former since it's easier to follow for JavaScript beginners, but you might want to change that in a later step

**JavaScript**

```js
// Import Node's spawn method
const { spawnSync } = require('child_process');

// Get path of active file
const activeEditorPath = atom.workspace.getActiveTextEditor().getPath();

// Spawn child process
const child = spawnSync('python', ['path/to/your/script', activeEditorPath]);
```

**Python**

```py
import sys

# Get argument
active_editor_path = sys.argv[1]

# Print editor path
print(f'Active editor path: {active_editor_path}')
```